# What is the intution behind generative and discriminative models?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, generative-models

Lets say we have a dataset $D=(X,Y)$ and our aim is to find a model $f$ which maps our feature and target.

$f:X \rightarrow Y$

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model),

A **discriminative model** is a model of the conditional probability of the target Y, given an observation X,

$P(Y|X)$

and a **generative model** is a statistical model of the joint probability distribution on X × Y symbolically

$P(X,Y)=P(X|Y)P(Y)$

Using Bayesian interpretation we can say that a discriminative model finds the posterior probability(LHS) and the generative model calculates the joint probability of likelihood and prior(RHS).

Isn't the discriminative model and generative model doing the same thing?

if it says a model estimates the conditional probability of the target, that is, $P(Y|X)$ using the Bayesian equation can't we assume that it also approximates the RHS of Bayesian equation and vice versa.

$P(Y|X) = \frac{P(X|Y)P(Y)}{P(X)}$

Why it feels like that discriminative and generative models are doing the same thing but mathematician uses LHS of Bayesian equation to describe the discriminative model and RHS for generative modelling?

A minor question is regarding the marginal probability $P(X)$ of generative model, why it was not included in the main equation of generative model $P(X,Y)=P(X|Y)P(Y)$ ?